# Using Cache to Create and Update User Cart

Tags: php, caching, laravel

I have created an application which has a cart. Currently the cart is a table in the database. Each cart is identified by a unique key generated and stored in a session.
However, in order to make interaction with my cart much faster I decided to use cache. However, I have never used it before and I am totally confused as to how it works even though I read all the docs.

For example when I create a cache object is it unique to that user in particular or do I have to generate some form of id to identify user A from user B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sessions and cache have multiple drivers for storage in Laravel. The default driver for both is file. To speed this up you can choose memcached, redis or apc.

Sessions are always specific to one user. Cache however is shared over the whole application (for every user). **For security reasons: store user specific content always in the session!**

So you've to use sessions for this and you can speed up session item look up by changing session storage driver. You can configure the session driver in `config/session.php`